# Session_start not running

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have just started teaching myself dotNet with C# and have hit a problem. Basically I have a variable that I want initialised when the page is first loaded. I have tried to use Session_Start to do this. However when I put a breakpoint at that point, it never seems to get there.

What I am not understanding?

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int numTries;

    protected void Session_start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numTries = 3;
    }

    protected void CheckNum_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numTries>0)
        {
            numTries--;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Answer.InnerText = "You have "+numTries.ToString()+" changes left.";
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Guess a number between 1 & 100 &nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="Guess" runat="server" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="OK" id="CheckNum" runat="server" onserverclick="CheckNum_ServerClick" />
        <br /><br />
        <p id="Answer" runat="server"></p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Visual Studio Community 2013

Comment: `Session_Start` is not an event of the page lifecycle, but of the *session* lifecycle, which is broader than the page. You want to do that in `Page_Load`. Additional reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Many thanks for that.

Comment: you're most welcome, glad to help. If that resolved your problem, I think I'll add it as an answer, for future references.